# Android reading multiple mp3 files

Tags: android

This question has two parts

First

I read multiple mp3 files from my phones storage (a few hundreds) and save them in an ArrayList of class Song which I made

```
class Song
{
    String name, path, album, artist, duration;
    Bitmap cover;
}
```

And I keep running out of memory, so how should I save them?

Second

Reading the files is quite slow, I curently use this

```
File directory = new File("/storage/3666-6134/Music");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
{
    Song temp = new Song(file.getAbsolutePath());
    songs.add(temp);
}
```

I'm going to guess that there is a faster and/or better way to do this

Thank you

Edit:
Seem that the slowness is also coming from MediaMetadataRetriever setDataSource
Is there a faster alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) for my music application.

For that first of all you'll have to get data which is already stored by [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) after that query through cursor and iterate cursor for each result so at the end your code will look like this:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
  //get columns
  int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
  int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
  int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
  //add songs to list
  do {
    long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
    String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
    String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
    songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
  }
  while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

You can even create standard code from music player from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding it in ArrayList? Is it for playing purposes? If yes, how about just save the path in the ArrayList then just do what you need to do when you need to play it or display it.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your approach:

1. You get `OOM` issue because you are loading all hundreds of `Bitmap`s into memory which is not a good idea. That the reason why you got crash. Try to use `WeakReference` instead.
2. The loading file list is pretty fast, the slow part is your decoding `Bitmap` part (I gess). Try to use another `Thread` to lazy load your `Bitmap`.